# Best way to merge two lines with same pattern

Tags: shell

I have a text file like below
Input:

> 05-29-2015,03:15:00,SESM1_0,ABC,interSesm,REDIRECTED_CALLS,0
>
> 05-29-2015,03:15:00,SESM1_0,ABC,interSesm,CALLS_TREATED,0

I am wondering the best way to merge two lines into:

> 05-29-2015,03:15:00,SESM1_0,ABC,interSesm,REDIRECTED_CALLS,0,CALLS_TREATED,0

Answer (score 2):

With this as the input file:

```
$ cat file
05-29-2015,03:15:00,SESM1_0,ABC,interSesm,REDIRECTED_CALLS,0
05-29-2015,03:15:00,SESM1_0,ABC,interSesm,CALLS_TREATED,0
```

We can get the output you want with:

```
$ awk -F, -v OFS=, 'NR==1{first=$0;next;} {print first,$6,$7;}' file
05-29-2015,03:15:00,SESM1_0,ABC,interSesm,REDIRECTED_CALLS,0,CALLS_TREATED,0
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a more general solution that reads both files, item by item, where items are separated by comma. After the first mismatch, remaining items from the first line are appended to the output, followed by remaining items from the second line.

The most complicated tool this uses is `sed`. Looking at it again, even sed can be replaced.

```
#!/bin/bash
inFile="$1"
tmp=$(mktemp -d)
sed -n '1p' <"$inFile" | tr "," "\n" > "$tmp/in1"
sed -n '2p' <"$inFile" | tr "," "\n" > "$tmp/in2"
{ while true; do
  read -r f1 <&3; r1=$?
  read -r f2 <&4; r2=$?
  [ $r1 -ne 0 ] || [ $r2 -ne 0 ] && break
  [ $r1 -ne 0 ] && echo "$f2"
  [ $r2 -ne 0 ] && echo "$f1"
  if [ "$f1" == "$f2" ]; then
    echo "$f1"
  else
    while echo "$f1"; do
      read -r f1 <&3 || break
    done
    while  echo "$f2"; do
      read -r f2 <&4 || break
    done
  fi
done; } 3<"$tmp/in1" 4<"$tmp/in2" | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's/.$/\n/'
rm -rf "$tmp"
```

Assuming your input file looks like this:

```
$ cat in.txt 
05-29-2015,03:15:00,SESM1_0,ABC,interSesm,REDIRECTED_CALLS,0
05-29-2015,03:15:00,SESM1_0,ABC,interSesm,CALLS_TREATED,0
```

You can then run the script as:

```
$ ./merge.sh in.txt 
05-29-2015,03:15:00,SESM1_0,ABC,interSesm,REDIRECTED_CALLS,0,CALLS_TREATED,0
```